# matplotlib imprime varias gráficas en lugar de una sola

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Tengo un código en Python que lee un dataframe, lo filtra y convierte a una gráfica con los valores TMIN y TMAX como "y" y las fechas como "x". Quiero que se imprima una gráfica de líneas con los valores mencionados anteriormente, pero me percato que al momento de ejecutar el código se imprimen varias veces otras gráficas que no quiero.
El código es el siguiente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mplleaflet
import pandas as pd

def leaflet_plot_stations(binsize, hashid):

    df = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinSize_d{}.csv'.format(binsize))

    station_locations_by_hash = df[df['hash'] == hashid]

    lons = station_locations_by_hash['LONGITUDE'].tolist()
    lats = station_locations_by_hash['LATITUDE'].tolist()

    plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))

    plt.scatter(lons, lats, c='r', alpha=0.7, s=200)
    
    #---my code---
    #1. Read the documentation and familiarize yourself with the dataset, then write some python code which returns a line graph 
    #of the record high and record low temperatures by day of the year over the period 2005-2014. The area between the record 
    #high and record low temperatures for each day should be shaded.
    
    df2 = pd.read_csv('data/C2A2_data/BinnedCsvs_d400/fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89.csv')
    df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])
    
    df2[(df2['Date'] > '2005-01-01') & (df2['Date'] < '2014-12-31')]
    #sorting by date to make the data reading easier
    df2 = df2.sort_values(by="Date")
    
    #groupyingby the min and max
    df2 = df2.groupby('Date')['Data_Value'].agg([('TMIN','min'), ('TMAX','max')])
    
    #this other syntaxis is valid, but due to the version of the current library it causes an error, that's why I used the 
    #method above
    
    #df2.groupby('Date').agg(TMIN = ('Data_Value', 'min'), TMAX = ('Data_Value', 'max'))
    
    #reseting the index so I can use the dates further on
    df2 = df2.reset_index()
    
    #creating the line graph
    #plt.figure()
    
    ax = df2.plot(x ='Date', y='TMIN', kind = 'line')

    #add second line to plot
    
    df2.plot('Date','TMAX',secondary_y=True, ax=ax)
    
    plt.xlabel('Date')
    plt.ylabel('Temperature Frequency')
    plt.title('Record high and record low temperatures by day of the year over the period 2005-2014')
    #plt.legend(['TMIN', 'TMAX'])
    plt.show()
    
    #to shade the area between high and low data
    #plt.fill_between(df2['TMIN'],df2['TMAX'], interpolate=True, color='grey', alpha=0.5)
    
    return plt.show()

leaflet_plot_stations(400,'fb441e62df2d58994928907a91895ec62c2c42e6cd075c2700843b89')
```

La tabla no la puedo publicar por motivos personales pero sí puedo compartir cómo se ve:

```
|   |Date   |TMIN   |TMAX|
|:--------- |:------:| -------:|-------:|
|0  |2005-01-01 |-56|156|
|1  |2005-01-02|-56 |139|
|2  |2005-01-03|0   |133|
|3  |2005-01-04|-39 |39|
|4  |2005-01-05|-94 |33|
```

Las gráficas que me imprime son las siguientes: Debo de hacer notar que solo quiero la última:
[image: Gráfica que no necesito pero me la imprime]

[image: Gráfica que quiero]

Debo de hacer notar que también la siguiente línea me falla: `plt.fill_between(df2['TMIN'],df2['TMAX'], interpolate=True, color='grey', alpha=0.5)`  Lo que intento hacer es llenar el espacio entre las líneas de TMIN y TMAX, leí la documentación y busqué en foros pero no sé por qué no me está funcionando, si alguien de paso podría ayudarme con ese problema adicional lo apreciaría.

Soy relativamente nuevo en matplotlib entonces apreciaría algo de paciencia. Gracias de antemano y disculpen las molestias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Antes que nada, en Stack Overflow es necesario escribir una sola pregunta por publicación para que otros usuarios puedan encontrar la información fácilmente, tu pusiste 2 preguntas en tu publicación

1. ¿Por qué sale más de una gráfica?
2. ¿Cómo rellenar entre `TMIN` y `TMAX`?

Respuestas:

1. La gráfica con los puntos (Se llama `scatter`) te aparece porque tienes una línea donde estás solicitando que se dibuje, comenta o quita esta línea `plt.scatter(lons, lats, c='r', alpha=0.7, s=200)`. De hecho, una línea antes afecta el tamaño del `scatter` por lo que la podrías quitar también (`plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))`)
2. Para rellenar entre `TMIN` y `TMAX` es necesario trasladar la gráfica de `TMAX` a la escala de `TMIN` ya que como tienen escalas diferentes no puedes hacerlo de forma directa

Primero hay que asignar cada gráfica a una variable para que sea más fácil trabajar con ellas

```
ax1 = df.plot(x ='Date', y='TMIN', kind = 'line')
ax2 = df.plot(x ='Date', y='TMAX',secondary_y=True, ax=ax1)
```

Luego tenemos que calcular la nueva posición de `ax2` en la escala de `ax1` (La llamé `ny`), para no estar escribiendo todo el tiempo `df['TMIN']` y `df['TMAX']` hice dos variables que son `y1` y `y2`

```
y1 = df['TMIN']
y2 = df['TMAX']

ny = ((y2-np.min(y2))/(np.max(y2)-np.min(y2)))*(np.max(y1)-np.min(y1))+np.min(y1)
```

Y por último tenemos que rellenar el espacio entre `ax1` y `ny`, pero hay dos secciones, donde `ax1` es mayor o igual a `ny` y donde `ax1` es menor o igual a `ny`

```
ax1.fill_between(df['Date'],y1,ny, where=y1<=ny, interpolate=True, color='grey', alpha=0.5)
ax1.fill_between(df['Date'],y1,ny, where=y1>=ny, interpolate=True, color='grey', alpha=0.5)
```

Juntando todo el código antes mencionado te queda así:

```
ax1 = df.plot(x ='Date', y='TMIN', kind = 'line')
ax2 = df.plot(x ='Date', y='TMAX',secondary_y=True, ax=ax1)

y1 = df['TMIN']
y2 = df['TMAX']

ny = ((y2-np.min(y2))/(np.max(y2)-np.min(y2)))*(np.max(y1)-np.min(y1))+np.min(y1)

ax1.fill_between(df['Date'],y1,ny, where=y1<=ny, interpolate=True, color='grey', alpha=0.5)
ax1.fill_between(df['Date'],y1,ny, where=y1>=ny, interpolate=True, color='grey', alpha=0.5)

plt.xlabel('Date')
plt.ylabel('Temperature Frequency')
plt.title('Record high and record low temperatures by day of the year over the period 2005-2014')

plt.show()
```

La prueba de que funciona (Utilicé la misma información que pusiste como ejemplo)

[image: Evidencia del código funcionando]

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la ayuda, en serio. Y le ofrezco una disculpa enorme a la comunidad por las molestias que pudo haber generado mi pregunta.

Comment: Disculpa, me está saliendo el error:  ```ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'' ``` en la línea  ```ax1.fill_between(df2['Date'],y1,ny, where=y1<=ny, interpolate=True, color='grey', alpha=0.5)```

Comment: Buen día, por favor crea una nueva pregunta y agrega todo el código que tienes. Sin ver lo que has hecho no me es posible saber de donde viene el error. Cuando crees la nueva pregunta ponme el link aquí para que pueda encontrarla fácilmente. Saludos!

Comment: Buen día, acabo de editar esta misma publicación con el código que tengo, muchas gracias. :)

Comment: Buen día, es necesario hacer una sola pregunta por publicación, esta sería la tercera pregunta en la misma publicación. Y ahora el código que muestras no refleja el problema inicial. Por favor edita tu pregunta cómo estaba y crea una nueva pregunta con este nuevo problema

Comment: @AvocadoToast , por cierto, el error `isfinite` por lo regular aparece si el `datatype` de tu arreglo no es aceptado por alguna función, revisa el tipo de datos de cada arreglo, esa información es necesaria para saber de dónde viene el problema

Comment: Una disculpa, la publicación es la siguiente: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/519567/error-extraño-al-momento-de-querer-agregar-una-gráfica-scatter-a-una-gráfica-con